# scrollbar hide behind the statusbar

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

I wrote a notepad. But I have a problem that I did not find an answer anywhere else. When the status bar is Enable, the load scroll is hidden behind the status bar. And this is a bug.

here design details

```
        // StatusBar1
        // 
        this.StatusBar1.Items.AddRange(new 
  System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.toolStripStatusLabel1,
        this.statusbar_lbl});
        this.StatusBar1.LayoutStyle = 

  System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLayoutStyle.HorizontalStackWithOverflow;
        this.StatusBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 161);
        this.StatusBar1.Name = "StatusBar1";
        this.StatusBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(480, 22);
        this.StatusBar1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.StatusBar1.Visible = false;
```

any help appreciated

[image]

Comment: We don't have any design details about your form.  Try `textBox1.BringToFront();`

Comment: Thanks, @LarsTech! Although this thread is old, it worked for me.